# Installing new Theme in Wordpress gives error Internal Server Error

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I purchased wordpress Ecommerce Theme from themeforest. I am trying to install this theme but after upload progress 35 - 40% it gives me internal Server error.

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: @MuthaFury I am new to wordpress. Can you tell me where will I get log file?

Comment: you're using linux?

Comment: @MuthaFury No I am using windows server

Comment: you're using apache or iis?

Comment: @MuthaFury It's iis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118187/discussion-between-muthafury-and-sun).